# FXCOP in x86 and x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

We have integrated fxcop in VS 2010 in our local system. Our local systems are x86. But when we provide the same settings for server, we are getting the error since the Server is x64 bit.

How do we provide the conditional post build to take x86 or x64?
Please provide any solutions

Comment: Could you post the settings you have done.

Comment: We have given the condition in post build to take either 64 or 86. Its working fine now. We had used CCNet to build and deploy and its throwing error now. Any idea on that?

Comment: Instead of we assuming "the error" it would be nice if you post the actual error.

Comment: Make sure you install FxCop binaries to a general folder such as `C:\FxCop`, not `C:\Program Files\`, as the latter becomes `C:\Program Files (x86)\` on Windows x64.